# Why this code is not showing table in browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, sqldatareader

In following asp c# code I am trying to display the content of database table using SqlDataReader, but it is not working. This code only handles the button click event. How can I make it work?

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = null;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (con)
        {
            con.ConnectionString = CS;
            DataTable dTbl = new DataTable();
            dTbl.Columns.Add("ID");
            dTbl.Columns.Add("Name");
            dTbl.Columns.Add("Salary");
            SqlCommand vmd = new SqlCommand();
            vmd.Connection = con;
            vmd.CommandText = "select * from [dbo].[employee]";
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = vmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                DataRow dRow = dTbl.NewRow();
                dRow["ID"] = dr[0];
                dRow["Name"] = dr[1];
                dRow["Salary"] = dr[2];
                dTbl.Rows.Add(dRow);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `while` code block add

```
GridView1.DataSource = dTbl;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

and remove that `GridView1.DataBind();` from beginning of Your code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need this line. remove it from beginning of your code:

```
GridView1.DataBind();//Remove
```

And then Place this two line after `While` loop:

```
GridView1.DataSource = dTbl;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

**Edit**: Also you can do it more simple like this:

```
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
      try
      {
           con.Open();
           SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from [dbo].[employee]", con);
           SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
           GridView1.DataSource = reader;
           GridView1.DataBind();
       }
       catch
       {
         //Handle error
       }
}
```